# Debugger for C# or Visual Studio that Print Debugging information

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Is there any Debugger for C#, that Print Data on Selected Break point

For Example:

I write a Custom Class and when add debug point on Any Object of that class then debugger print value in some file or Console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Print to the Output window with tracepoints.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx)

[image]